Use Google Drive images on a generate html
I would like to generate before a form in my html an overview of all the existing images (thumbnail) format on the webpage.
So the users can select one photo that will copy on do the form also in this page.  Submitting the form will only send the number of the selected images and all the data that are entered in the form.  I can't find a way how to do this:
This is the base in html for selecting the image - based on radiobuttoms but disabled via CSS). By this ways you can only choose one image.  The aim is via javascript copy the selected reference into the form element that follows.
See example of the html:
<div>
    <label>`not used`
        <input type="radio"name="kies"  id="6" >`hidden`
        <img class="pic" src="zomaar-7.jpg" id="p6" value="6" alt="Option 6" onclick="selectedPhoto(this.id);`show image 7`">
    </label>
    <label>`not used`
        <input type="radio" name="kies" id="7" >`hidden`
        <img class="pic" src="zomaar-8.jpg" id="p7" value="7" alt="Option 7" onclick="selectedPhoto(this.id);"`show image 8`>
    </label>
</div>

Later on the radio button will be formatted by 4 on a line and will displaying all the images that are in one subdirectory.
How can I do this that the "src" element refers to an image of the folder. I have already a simulater application that generate a form base on data in Excel and there I pass the info using var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html'); in combination with a variable tmp where everything I contains all the values I like to use in the html. And this works fine.
